# Spring boot update item using Putmapping required all column in requestbody

Tags: spring-boot, rest, put

I have a table **Product** including about 5 columns: **upc, product_name, brand, category, price** with **upc** is the unique value and I set it as **Primary Key**.

Now I want to update any specific column base on **upc**, I've already made it done but it always asked to put all column variables into **RequestBody** although I just want to update one column.

For example, I want to update `productName` from **Nivea** to **Dove**, I have to use this long RequestBody:

```
{    
    "upc": "100101101111",
    "productName" : "Dove",
    "brand": "Procter & Gamble",
    "category" : "Bath and Body",
    "description": "Shampoo"
}
```

If I missed even one key in the **RequestBody**, I will get the error code `500`. Is it possible if I can just put only 2 columns: **upc** for specific product that I want to update, and the other column with the value I want to update?

For example, I want to update productName from **Nivea** to **Dove**, how can I do like this:

```
   {    
        "upc": "100101101111",
        "productName" : "Dove",
    }
```

Hers is my `updateProduct` function:

```
@Override
public Status updateProduct(Product product) {
    List<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
    for (Product prod : products) {
        if (prod.getUpc().equals(product.getUpc())) {
            productRepository.save(product);
            return Status.SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    return Status.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND;

}
```

and my `controller`:

```
@PutMapping("/updateproduct")
public ResponseEntity<String> updateProduct(String upc, @RequestBody Product product) {
    Status stt = productService.updateProduct(product);

    if (stt == Status.SUCCESS) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Product Updated Successfully!");
    }
    else if (stt == Status.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Product with upc = " + product.getUpc() + " Not Found!");
    }
    else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it is unnecessary to execute a `findAll` query as your `upc` field is unique, you would be pulling all records for a potentially massive table.
Now here's a potential way to do what you are trying to achieve:

```
@Override
public Status updateProduct(Product product) {
    Product prod = productRepository.findByUpc(product.getUpc());
    
    if (product.getProductName() != null && !Objects.equals(prod.getProductName(), product.getProductName())) {
        prod.setProductName(product.getProductName());
        productRepository.save(prod);
    }

    return Status.SUCCESS;
}
```

You could add multiple if checks and adjust the logic to the fields that you would like the user to be able to update. In this way you are getting the entity from the database and only modifying the fields that the request contains.
Note that if you use this convention for what is being updated, you won't be able to set something to null. It would also be nice to use a `DTO` object instead of the same entity class in your requests.

Comment: After adding "public Product findByUpc(Product product);" to Repository and trying your code then I got an error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [com.ecommerce.ecommerce.model.inventory.Product@15bccfa4] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]"

Comment: The repository method in your case should take a string as  an argument (your `upc`), not `Product`.

Comment: Your solution works great but there's also a problem. After I add multiple if checks, it can only update a single column.  What if I want to update single column or multiple columns?

Comment: No, it will work for multiple columns, too. Just add multiple checks and assignments and save your entity.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it correctly. I was adding         else if (product.getBrand() != null && !Objects.equals(prod.getBrand(), product.getBrand())) {
            prod.setBrand(product.getBrand());
            productRepository.save(prod);
        }
else if (...) after your if. But it only can update single column

Comment: If you use else if the condition will only be checked if the first condition is not met. Use multiple if statements, not if...else if...else if.